# How to prove matrix Q is equal to $E_{m}+\lambda e_{p}e^{T}_{q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove that this holds true, where $e_{p}, e_{q}$ are unit vectors.:

$Q^{p}_{q}\left( \lambda \right) =\left( \delta _{ij}+\lambda \delta _{ip}\delta _{jq}\right)_{i=1,...,m\\j=1,...,m} = E_{m}+\lambda e_{p}e^{T}_{q}$
where $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i=j$ and zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we were to represent $\delta_{ip}$ is a vector, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}\delta_{1p} \\ \vdots \\ \delta_{p-1,p}\\ \delta_{pp} \\ \delta_{p+1,p} \\ \vdots \\\delta_{mp}\end{bmatrix} $$
Note that $\delta_{ip} = 1$ only when $ i = p$, hence the only values that is non zeros is $\delta_{pp}$, we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}\delta_{1p} \\ \vdots \\ \delta_{p-1,p}\\ \delta_{pp} \\ \delta_{p+1,p} \\ \vdots \\\delta_{mp}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ \vdots \\ 0\\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=e_p $$
Likewise, representing the term $\delta_{jq}$ will give us $e_q$. Hence the term $\lambda e_pe_q^T$ should be clear.

As for the term $\delta_{ij}$, we have that $\delta_{ij} = 1$ only when $i=j$ else it is zero, hence we get the identity matrix $E_m$.